# Insert FB birthday into Mysql gives NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I Get NULL when i insert the Birthday and current time in MYSQL

```
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$params['access_token']."&format=json&fields=birthday";
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url),true);
     echo("birthday is " . $user['birthday']);
```

SQL

```
$queryip = "insert into table (birthday,currenttime) values (".$user['birthday'].','.CURDATE().")";
                $resultip = mysql_query($queryip);
```

MYSQL Structure 
Both the birthday,currenttime fields are Type `DATE`

Comment: `CURDATE()` is a MySQL function, not PHP so it should be contained within the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to request the `birthday_date` column, not `birthday`, because it's always in the same format, DDMMYYY.
After that, you need to add the following to your INSERT query:

```
STR_TO_DATE('" . mysql_real_escape_string ($user ['birthday_date']) . "', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: I am using PHP / MYSQL > this statement is showing syntax error.

Comment: +1 for escaping at least! @AdiMathur: `STR_TO_DATE` is a MySQL function, not a PHP one. You need to understand the different between PHP and MySQL. What Jeroen has written more or less replaces `".$user['birthday'].'`. Follow Michael Mior's advice too.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP:

```
function formatDateFbToSql($fbdate)
{
    // facebook user_birthday format (02/19/1988)
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $fbdate);
    // mysql format (1988-02-19)
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Despite being a different language and RDBMS, this is the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10461630/372643).)

Firstly, SQL strings must be contained in `''`: you're clearly missing them in `(".$user['birthday'].' ...`. Secondly, and more importantly, they **must** be escaped, to prevent SQL injection attacks (and to make sure the string is valid anyway).

In general, it's better to use prepared statements to pass the parameters to SQL query instead of inserting the variables in the query itself: this should take care of the escaping and conversion for you.

You'll also need to cast the birthday string into a date if necessary.

I'd recommend using [`mysqli` and prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead. (There are a number of examples out there, perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9285654/372643) would help.)

**EDIT:**

Try something along these lines perhaps (assuming you've switched to `mysqli`):

```
$query = "insert into table (birthday,currenttime) values (STR_TO_DATE(?, '%m/%d/%Y'), CURDATE())";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare()) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $user['birthday']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    die($mysqli->error);
}
```

(This might need to be `birthday_date` as Jeroen suggested too.)

Comment: @Bruno- the birthday in the datebase is comming as 0000-00-00

Comment: Use `STR_TO_DATE` as @Jeroen suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try replacing ".$user['birthday'].','.CURDATE()." into '".$user['birthday']."',CURDATE()  ?

Comment: the birthday in the datebase is comming as 0000-00-00 but the time is comming fine now..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$user['birthday'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($user['birthday']));
```

before the SQL insert statement.